# How do I set and list page_template with wpcli?

Tags: pages, page-template, wp-cli, command-line

I have a page that has a new template, and I want to set that new template with wp-cli.

When I `wp post get <id>` I get an output like the following:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+
| Field                 | Value               |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
| ID                    | 4                   |
| post_author           | 5                   |
| post_date             | 2012-03-09 13:11:38 |
| post_date_gmt         | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| post_content          |                     |
| post_title            | Home Page           |
| post_excerpt          |                     |
| post_status           | publish             |
| comment_status        | closed              |
| ping_status           | open                |
| post_password         |                     |
| post_name             | home                |
| to_ping               |                     |
| pinged                |                     |
| post_modified         | 2015-06-04 12:23:41 |
| post_modified_gmt     | 2015-06-04 19:23:41 |
| post_content_filtered |                     |
| post_parent           | 0                   |
| guid                  | /?page_id=4         |
| menu_order            | 0                   |
| post_type             | page                |
| post_mime_type        |                     |
| comment_count         | 0                   |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

This doesn't have the attribute I am looking for `page_template`

When I try what seems to be the correct attribute key:
`wp post update 4 --page_template='New Home Page'`

I get `Warning: The page template is invalid.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that in the [documentation](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/create/) for wp-cli it says

> `[--<field>=<value>]` Associative args for the new post. See
>   [wp_insert_post().](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Which then subsequently shows:

> ```
> 'page_template'  => [ <string> ] // Requires name of template file, eg. template.php.
> ```

The command is `wp post update 4 --page_template='new-home.php'`

Answer (score 3):

> This doesn't have the attribute I am looking for `page_template`

Try using `page_template` in `fields`:

```
wp post list --post_type=page,post --fields=ID,post_title,post_name,post_type,page_template
```