# WP-CLI not setting page template with page_template="template-name.php"

Tags: page-template, wp-cli

I'm having trouble setting the page template with wp-cli.  According to this post, [How do I set and list page_template with wpcli](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190540/how-do-i-set-and-list-page-template-with-wpcli), it looks like:

```
wp post create --post_type=page --page_template='template-name.php'
```

should work, but it only returns "Error: The page template is invalid."  Any thoughts? I've tried creating the page first and then updating using wp post update 14 --page_template='template-name.php' and that says "Success: Updated post 14." but nothing is changed when I look at the page in the Wordpress admin.

Thanks for help on this. Today is my first day working with wp-cli and it is incredible.  I wish I would have come across this a long time ago.

Comment: Of course. Now I figured it out.  The problem was that my templates were in a folder in my theme called "templates" (I use foundationPress).  I did a wp post meta list post_name="post-name" and is showed that it is in the folder templates.  Then I changed the above code to wp post create --post_type=page --page_template='template/template-name.php' and it worked fine.

Comment: btw, in case someone in the same situation finds this the command `wp post meta list post_name="post-name"` is incredibly useful, especially if you use advanced custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this as a comment, but should have put it here.

The problem was that my templates were in a folder in my theme called "templates"

I found this out by doing:

```
wp post meta list post_name="post-name"
```

and is showed that it is in the folder templates. Then I changed the above code to

```
wp post create --post_type=page --page_template='template/template-name.php'
```

This worked fine